# Calling a method of Service directly instead of using startService()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, android-lifecycle

I'm trying to connect to a `Service` using `bindService()`. 
I am able to obtain reference to the `Service` in `onServiceConnected()` method of `ServiceConnection`.

My question is if I declare a method say `downloadFile()` in `Service` and call it through the `Service` object from an `Activity` rather than calling `startService()` and then calling `downloadFile()` from `onStartCommand()`, then what is the difference between the two approaches ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between the two approaches ?

The method you are proposing is a wrong-headed approach, for three reasons:

- In Android, `Activity`s and `Service`s are considered to be ***app components***. A component should be treated as an independent entity whose internal methods are not directly called by other components/classes. Such a ***component*** should be started using an `Intent` and then left to do its own work.
- If you don't call `startService()`, you literally never start the `Service`. How then would you call a method defined inside it ? And manually creating instances of classes that are ***app components*** is frowned upon in Android. You should never do something like

  ```
  new Service()
  ```

  or

  ```
  new Activity()
  ```

  That's just bad and you're inviting a whole lot of trouble.
- If you are going to call `downloadFile()` directly from your `Activity`, then why put it in a `Service` in the first place ? Isn't that redundant ? The reason for putting it in a `Service` is that the download operation is a non-UI task that requires no user interaction, which is what a `Service` is meant for. An `Activity`, on the other hand, is a UI-based component that is explicitly meant for user interaction. If the user dismisses your `Activity` while the download is in progress, then a `NullPointerException` gets thrown when the download completes and your code tries to post the data on the UI.

Comment: thanks. what i meant to ask was just as we call start() for thread and it calls rn after getting the thread allocated .is there any such thing or simply startService is passing the intent to onStartCommand after creating service onCreate method.

Comment: The correct way is to call `startService(intent)` in your `Activity` and call `downloadFile()` in the `onStartCommand()` method of your `Service`. That's all.

Comment: can we not get a reference to the service object even without startService by using bindService and getting a reference to service using binder. thanks for a nice explanation

Comment: You ***can*** get a reference to a `Service` that way, but you should avoid calling `downloadFile()` via the reference.